# SSIS: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Datetime' to type 'System.Char[]'

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis

I try to migrating MSSQL to PostgreSQL using SSIS and JDBC Driver.

But, it occurs error message

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Datetime' to type
>   'System.Char[]'.

MSSQL type is datetime, PostgreSQL type is timestamptz

But it is failed...

How should I do?

Comment: Did you figure this out @ko_ma?

Comment: @richardwhatever no. I dont know yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I've found to do this is to recast the field on SQL Server to string, then do the migration. PostgreSQL will automatically identify it as a timestamp. If it is a nullable datetime it will not and you'll have to coerce the field from varchar to timestamp.

Comment: It worked for me, that's odd...
Thanks for the tip !

Comment: I have been struggling with the same issue for a couple of days now, thanks for the help!